# Get buildid in teamcity

Tags: teamcity

I would like to get the buildId (such as #2594) of the current teamcity job as an input to my script. I tried:

```bash
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    python store_test_artifacts.py --buildId %system.build.number%
fi
```

But this leads to the error:

```
There are no compatible agents which can run this build.
```

and

```
Implicit requirements:

 system.teamcity.build.id defined in Build step: Setup
```

How can I pass the buildID shown in teamcity to my script?

Answer (score 0):

It's available as a environment variable:

```
echo $BUILD_NUMBER
```